# push_back to std::vector creates many temp objects compared to std::list

Tags: c++, stl

I created a class for keeping track of instances with a unique ID.
Constructing a new instance of this class (or copy copy constructing it) provides a unique ID, taken from a pool of IDs. Destructing puts the ID back to the pool. Print statements observe when an instance is created and destroyed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>


class IdPool {
public:
    IdPool()  {
        m_id = allocateID();
        std::cout << "c'tor id: " << m_id << std::endl;
    }

    ~IdPool() {
        freeID(m_id);
        std::cout << "d'tor free id: " << m_id << std::endl;
    }
    IdPool(const IdPool& obj) {
        m_id = allocateID();
        std::cout << "copy c'tor id: " << m_id << std::endl;
    }

    class Init {
    public:
        Init(const int maxIDs) {
            for (int i=maxIDs; i>=1; --i) {
                s_idArray.push_back(i);
            };
        }
    };

    int id() { return m_id; }

private:
    int allocateID() {
        if (s_idArray.empty()) 
            return 0;
        else {
            int id = s_idArray.back();
            s_idArray.pop_back();
            return id;
        }
    }

    bool freeID(int id) {
        if ( (id > 0 ) && (s_idArray.size() < s_maxIdCount) ) {
            s_idArray.push_back(id);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static std::vector<int> s_idArray;
    static const size_t     s_maxIdCount;
    static Init             s_setIdCount;
    int                     m_id;
};


const size_t IdPool::s_maxIdCount = 10;
std::vector<int> IdPool::s_idArray;
IdPool::Init IdPool::s_setIdCount(IdPool::s_maxIdCount);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    cout << endl << "-- push 2 IDs to list --" << endl;
    list<IdPool> listId;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        listId.push_back(IdPool());
        cout << "push_back to list id: " << listId.back().id() << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "-- push 2 IDs to vector --" << endl;
    vector<IdPool> vecId;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        vecId.push_back(IdPool());
        cout << "push_back to vector id: " << vecId.back().id() << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "-- push 2 IDs to preallocated vector --" << endl;
    vector<IdPool> vecIdReserved;
    vecIdReserved.reserve(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        vecIdReserved.push_back(IdPool());
        cout << "push_back to reserved vector id: " << vecIdReserved.back().id() << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When testing the ID generator class I observed the following behavior:

List: pushing new IDs to a list works as expected (pull new ID for the temp object, put it back after the temp has been destroyed, see output.

Vector: pushing new IDs to the vector creates a number of temp objects, corresponding to the size of the vector. After each push_back operation the vector contains the same ID at the tail, see output below. This is not the desired behavior, if I want to use the IdPool class to identify instances of derived classes. I expected just one temp for each push_back operation, as for the list. What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
Pushing to preallocated vector works as for list. This might be the way to go in this case. I just need to remember to reserve before using the vector.

Output

```
-- push 2 IDs to list --
c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 2
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to list id: 2

c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 3
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to list id: 3


-- push 2 IDs to vector --
c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 4
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to vector id: 4

c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 5
d'tor free id: 4
copy c'tor id: 4
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to vector id: 4


-- push 2 IDs to preallocated vector --
c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 6
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to reserved vector id: 6

c'tor id: 1
copy c'tor id: 7
d'tor free id: 1
push_back to reserved vector id: 7
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit a [mcve] into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) doesn't work as you expected.
When vector's [capacity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) is equal to vector's [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size), it leads to reallocation. But the exact behavior is *implementation-defined*.

For the consideration of efficiency, push_back not only open up a small room just fit for another element(And that violates the time complexity requirement of C++ standard.), but it apply for a big size(typically, double the original size, that's why you said the size is correspond to the original size.)

To reduce reallocation' s time and avoid additional reallocation(but in fact, it cannot always be avoided by using reserve), use [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

to shrink the vector, use shrink_to_fit(but it cannot  be guaranteed to succeed, either.)

it seems that a [example](https://ideone.com/8M8S2t) is needed.

Comment: From what I heard, increasing capacity linearly would violate the standard requirement for `push_back` being O(1) amortized.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat NO, because it's amortized.  The following push_back operation don't need allocation. So the amortized time is constant.

Comment: By linear capacity growth I mean maintaining `size == capacity`, so reallocation happens on every insertion. I don't argue that increasing size by a constant factor gives you O(1) amortized insertion. What I'm saying is that no compilers *"open up a small room just fit for another element"* because that would no longer be O(1) amortized, thus violating the requirement.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, I didn't got your point. Now i understood what you want to tell me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so it is a supplement to my answer, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, i 'll correct my answer soon. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And, sorry for being a little rude just now.  :P

Comment: That wasn't rude at all, in my opinion.

Comment: You know that there is a good reason the growth-factor should stay significantly below 2? It's about the possibility of re-using allocations.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a correct explanation of why you were seeing so many copies, but there is a way to eliminate even more copies:  emplace_back.

As you've seen, when you write:

```
vecId.push_back(IdPool());
```

You invoke the default constructor for IdPool and then you invoke the copy constructor to copy it into the vector's storage.  (And, as the accepted answer explained, it may also have to make copies of elements already in the vector's storage if it has to increase the amount of storage available.)

But if you were to write:

```
vecId.emplace_back();
```

The new IdPool will be constructed directly in the vector's storage area, saving one copy.

Remember that vecId's type is `std::vector<IdPool>`, so the emplace_back knows that it needs to construct an IdPool.  And since we didn't pass any arguments to emplace_back, it knows to invoke IdPool's default constructor.

Suppose IdPool had an additional constructor that takes a name as a `std::string`:

```
explicit IdPool(std::string name) { blah, blah, blah }
```

You could also invoke this constructor with emplace_back, like this:

```
vecId.emplace_back("pool party!");
```

There's effectively an overload of emplace_back for every public constructor of the element type.

```
vector<IdPool> vecId;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    vecId.emplace_back();
    cout << "push_back to vector id: " << vecId.back().id() << endl << endl;
}
```